# DDD организация структуры проекта. Domain и DAL

Tags: c#, архитектура, ddd, domain

Вопрос по архитектуре. Проект делится на слои, каждый слой в отдельном проекте: App.Domain, App.DAL, App.Infrastructure, ...
App.Domain определяет сущности, App.DAL определяет интерфейсы доступа к данным, и dto-объекты сущностей.

Domain:

```
class User
{
    public string Login { get; private set;}
}
```

DAL:

```
interface IUserRepository
{
    List<User> GetAll();
    User FindById(int id);
    ...
}

class UserDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; private set;}
    public byte[] PasswordHash {get; private set;}
}
```

Вопрос - как инстанцировать объекты доменной области в DAL?
В классе User можно было бы определить конструтор User(UserDto dto), но тогда в доменном слое появляется зависимость от DAL.

Кроме передачи всех зависимостей в конструктор сущности есть другие решения?

Comment: Передавайте вместо dto в конструктор набор нужных полей и зависимости не будет.

Comment: @tym32167, подскажите, пожалуйста. Слой доступа к данным, персистентный слой и инфраструктурный - это названия одного и того же или это разные слои, отвечающие за разные вещи?

Comment: Хз что такое `инфраструктурный`, но `персистентный` и `Слой доступа к данным` имхо обычно означают одно и то же.

Comment: канонически, пользователь должен создаваться в репозиторие, который лежит в инфраструктурном слое. Интерфейсу репозитория допустимо лежать в доменном слое. DAL это из другой парадигмы ;)

Comment: другой вариант использовать ORM с шаблоном data mapper и тогда не придется создавать DTO объекты, а мапер всю это работу по передаче аругументов заберет на себя.